# best practice for DB & File search with lucene.net in a asp.net web application

Tags: asp.net, lucene.net

i have site where i need to develop site search functionality. the data may reside in database table or may in aspx page as static word. i search google and found that lucene.net may be appropriate for the site search functionality. but i never use lucene.net so i dont know how to create lucene.net index file. i want to develop 2 utility in my site like

1) one for create & update index file reading data from database table & physical aspx file.
2) utility which search multiple single or multiple keyword against index file.

i found a bit of code snippet which i just do not understand

```
string indexFileLocation = @"C:\Index";
    string stopWordsLocation = @"C:\Stopwords.txt";
    var directory = FSDirectory.Open(new DirectoryInfo(indexFileLocation));
    Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(
        Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_29, new FileInfo(stopWordsLocation));
```

what is **Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_29**  what is stopWordsLocation
how data need to store in Stopwords.txt

but have no concept to develop the above 2 utility. so please guide me how search my DB and as well as aspx files with lucene.net....i will be glad if some one discuss here with bit of sample code. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_29 just indicates the Lucene version your are using, you should always use the most up to date in new code. It is there for backward compatibility in case you upgrade your Lucene with a version that changes the StandardAnalyzer, but you dont want to re-index all your data.

The stopWordsLocation is the location of a file with your stop words, words you dont want to index.

IE: it, he, she, the, or, and etc...

Its a regular text file, each line should contain 1 stop word, and separate each line with a linebreak.

http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/3_0_1/api/all/org/apache/lucene/analysis/WordlistLoader.html#getWordSet(java.io.Reader)

Comment: how to rebuild the lucene.net index. is there any way to remove all indexes and recreate again. if shades some light. thanks

Comment: if you specify true in the IndexWriter's create parameter, it will erase the index prior to indexing. removing an index is as simple as deleting all files in the directory